# put/add is replacing all entires in a map or list

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a map: `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>`to a `Map<String, Settings>`.

The `Settings` class contains all the possible map keys and will be set to true when looping through this particular key.

The problem is when in the deepest map, when adding to a global `Map<String, Settings>`, the `Settings` will be replaved with the last `Settings` for every entry.

Can someone help me find out where i do wrong?

```
public void loop(Map map, Settings settings){

    List keys = new ArrayList(map.keySet());

    if(map.get(keys.get(0)) instanceof Map){
        //is a map, so continue loop + add to vorm

        for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++){
            Settings tmp = settings;  

            String field = keys.get(i).toString();
            Method method = null;
            try {
                //Set some booleans for key
                method = tmp.getClass().getMethod(field, boolean.class);
                method.invoke(tmp, true);

                loop((Map) map.get(keys.get(i).toString()), tmp);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
                Settings tmp = settings;

                String key = keys.get(i).toString();
                String word = map.get(key).toString();

                tmp.setWord(word);

                Settings input = tmp;
                settingsList.add(convert, input);//put into 2 arraylists
                keyList.add(convert, woord);
                convert++;
                //vormen.put(word, tmp);//put into list


        }
    }
}
```

This method is called here:

```
public void convert(){
    vormen = new HashMap();
    settingsList = new ArrayList<>();
    wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(jsonMap.isEmpty()){
        throw new NullPointerException("You are trying to convert a null map");
    }else {
        loop(jsonMap, new Settings());

    }
}
```

Not every variable might be correctly named, i just renamed them.

Thanks for you help

EDIT: fixed, the temporary Settings that was put into the arrays was somehow being changed every time, acting like a pointer or something. I made a new Settings just before adding, and set the settings of tmp to that one. It works now.

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>` ??? Hats off to you dude.

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example of what you're trying to build? Maybe there's a better and simpler solution than to nest Maps one inside another.

Comment: Maybe? There is no doubt in my mind that says there isn't a better solution.